# taking function with vector argument and defining new anonymous function with arbitrary subset of vector members as arguments

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I have a function `vector_function` that takes a 1 by 6 vector variable as its only argument. I would like to define an anonymous function `anon_fun` based on `vector_function` that specifies certain members of the 1 by 6 vector as arguments and assigns default values to the rest.

For example, if I wanted to create `anon_fun` using the first three members of the 1 by 6 vector variable as input arguments, I could write:

```
% Define default variable values.
var_def = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

% Set which variables to use as arguments.
var_flag = [true,true,true,false,false,false];

% Define anonymous function that takes 
anon_fun = @(var)...
vector_function([var(1),var(2),var(3),var_def(4),var_def(5),var_def(6)]);
```

Is there a way to handle all 2^6 = 64 possible permutations of `var_flag`? I could change the way `vector_function` takes input, but that will require significant recoding.

Comment: So `var_flag` is the input and `var_def` is static?

Comment: Yes, `var_def` will not change. Only the members of `var_flag` will change.

Comment: Why not have a function that takes, `var_def` and `var_flag` and process based on that? Is there a particular need to have 64 anonymous functions?

Comment: I am trying to fit a model to data points. `vector_function` in my case is a function that takes 6 model parameters as a vector and outputs the mean squared error. I want to fit different subsets of these 6 model parameters by using `fmincon` to minimize the mean squared error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following definition for `anon_fun`:

```
anon_fun = @(var) vector_function(var .* var_flag + var_def .* ~var_flag);
```